# Select and count specific values from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, select, count

I need some help with the following problem:

the data looks like

```
dt  value
15  0
15  2   
15  8   
15  8   
15  10  
16  12
15  19  
15  35  
15  45
16  45  
16  45  
15  50
15  0
16  26  
15  43
15  50  
15  0
.
.
.
```

now I have to sum up dt until value reaches 50, always beginning from 0.

I have tried the following, but I am not sure if it is right,

```
df['value'].values[(df['value'].values > 0) & (df['value'].values < 50)] = 1    
df =  df.assign(counter_col_x = df.loc[df['value'].eq(1)].groupby(df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()).ngroup())
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Does the series always end at  `50`? Or there might be data after?

Comment: could you show expected output?

Comment: `df.loc[df['value'].between(0,50, inclusive = False),'dt'].groupby(df['value'].ge(50).cumsum()).sum()`? or `size` instead `sum()`

Comment: @Quang Hoang no it could also be any other value. Expected output is the sum from 0 to 50 and then start again from zero to 50. This should be a new column

Comment: `df['value'].values[(df['value'].values > 0) & (df['value'].values < 50)] = 1  ` Won't that work without the `.values` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way if you didn't have to restart several time within a column would have been the cumulating sum of a series.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html

I hope you meant a cumulating sum of values until it reaches 50. I could only come up with a way of assigning the value of the Series in a loop. Hope that helps.

```
new_cum_sum = 0
list_of_values = []
for x, y in zip(test['dt'], test['value']):
    if y== 0:
        new_cum_sum = x
    elif y <= 50:
        new_cum_sum+=x
    list_of_values.append(new_cum_sum)

test['test_cum'] = list_of_values
```